# Kubernetes traffic on deployments

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

Off late, we have found many Kubernetes pods are running without any ingress/egress traffic. APM monitoring revealed the actual traffic flows in each pod.

Now, I would like to terminate those pods that doesn't have any traffic over the period of time. So that I can reduce the worker nodes.

I need your help on below query.

1. Is there a way we can find ingress/egress traffic at deployment level? Currently it shows at pod level. But if I generate the report it includes the pods that are already terminated. It is difficult for me to get historical report of pods. Because whenever the pods gets scaled, everytime it creates with new name.

Comment: Could you please check [this doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/#autoscaling-on-multiple-metrics-and-custom-metrics). In specific the paragraph starting with `"For example, if you had your monitoring system collecting metrics about network traffic"`? I need to make sure we are on the same page before proposing an answer.

Comment: Have you managed to make it work?

Comment: Could you please explain what kind of APM are you using? And have you tried to use HPA (for example based on http_requests custom metrics)?

Comment: I'm using newrelic. I'm finding some challenges getting historical data. So, looking for some native utility.

Comment: What about that [HPA](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/#autoscaling-on-multiple-metrics-and-custom-metrics) I have mentioned before? Have you tried that? Does it fits your requirements?